# PostgreSQL: Create Index in JSON Array

Tags: sql, arrays, json, postgresql, indexing

I am pretty new to postregSQL and not too familiar with SQL yet. But im trying to learn.
In my database i want to store huge JSON files (~2mio lines, 40mb) and later query them as fast as possible. Right now it is to slow, so i figured indexing should do the trick.
The Problem is i do not know how to index the file since it is a bit tricky. I am woking on it the whole day now and starting to get desperate..

My DB is calles "replays" the json column "replay_files"

So my files look like this:

```
"replay": [
    {
        "data": {
            "posX": 182,
            "posY": 176,
            "hero_name": "CDOTA_Unit_Hero_EarthSpirit"
        },
        "tick": 2252,
        "type": "entity"
    },
    {
        "data": {
            "posX": 123,
            "posY": 186,
            "hero_name": "CDOTA_Unit_Hero_Puck"
        },
        "tick": 2252,
        "type": "entity"
    }, ...alot more lines... ]}
```

I tried to get all the entries with say heron_name: Puck
So i tried this:

SELECT * FROM replays r, json_array_elements(r.replay_file#>'{replay}') obj WHERE obj->'data'->>'hero_name' = 'CDOTA_Unit_Hero_Puck';

Which is working but for smaller files.
So i want to index like that:

CREATE INDEX hero_name_index ON
    replays ((json_array_elements(r.replay_file#>'{replay}')->'data'->'hero_name);

BUt it doesn work. I have no idea how to reach that deep into the file and get to index this stuff.

I hope you understand my problem since my english isnt the best and can help me out here. I just dont know what else to try out.

Kind regards and thanks alot in advance
Peter

Comment: Check out jsonb indexing

Comment: @AlexandarMitsev You can include links here too. use `[text](http://example.com)` Check out jsonb indexing [datatype-json](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/datatype-json.html)